# Rails 4 CSV Generation of Index View without Code Duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, dry, code-duplication

How can I export my namespaced/resouce/index.html.erb content, which uses a partial for each row on the index page, into a CSV file, without duplicating code in the viewfile for the CSV (or in whichever method outputs the CSV)?

The controller looks like this:

```
class Namespaced::ResourceController < AncestorController
  def index
    @rows = current_object.rows.some_scope.page(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv do
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\""
        headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
     end
    end
  end
end
```

The index view just lists table headers:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <strong>Order ID</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Order Date</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Description</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Price</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Shipping</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Tax</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Total</strong>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <strong>Status</strong>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <%= render partial: "row", collection: @rows %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          Download: <%= link_to 'CSV', namespaced_resource_path(format: :csv) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The partial HTML view looks as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= row.order_id %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.row_date %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.description %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.price %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.shipping %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.tax %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.calculate_total %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= row.status %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

...and the CSV view is as such:

```
<%- headers = ['Order ID', 'Order Date', 'Description', 'Price', 'Shipping', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Status'] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<%- @rows.each do |entry| -%>
  <%= CSV.generate_line([
    row.order_id,
    row.row_date,
    row.description,
    row.price,
    row.shipping,
    row.tax,
    row.calculate_total,
    row.status
  ]) -%>
<%- end -%>
```

Note the same properties/callbacks used for the partial HTML view, and the  CSV view. Some of those are relatively complex decorator/helper callbacks, and might change / be omitted / have more added in the future. The headers are also added in both places (and they aren't all just attributes of the data model). So basically, this partial view and the CSV view exhibit code duplication.

While I can think of some techniques to populate the column headers and use the same callback functions, I'm not sure if it's conventional. I have a hunch there is a simple way to accomplish this that is built into the framework.

What is the most *Rails-4-ish* way to DRY this up? How can I have one single partial view that works for both the HTML index view and the CSV view?

Comment: Now that I think of it, there might not be a "Railsy" way to do this - the Rails generators duplicate code when they create the HTML and JSON views for controller actions. If there was a way to share the same procedures between them, I imagine the generators would do it automatically.